# How can a maternity refusal syndrome be prevented or treated?

Tags: clinical-psychology, depression, psychology

Despite being rare, a maternal refusal syndrome can have devasting consequences on children, spouse, and the mother herself.

It appears indeed that occasionally women don't bond that well to their kids, and this may be accompanied by a crisis in their marriage too.

The evidence on this is quite limited and confused with post-partum depression, which is a completely different entity (see for instance [Hardy](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2098475/We-didnt-love-babies-What-happens-maternal-instinct-just-doesnt-kick-Three-women-break-motherhood-s-greatest-taboo-.html), a Wikipedia entry on [maternal bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_bond), and [Ragdale](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/kith-and-kin/201312/the-maternal-myth)). Indeed, I mean by maternity refusal syndrome to the incapacity to bond effectively and rejoice with the kids not shortly after delivery.

How can it best be prevented and managed?

Comment: What is this syndrome? A quick search gave me nothing relevant. What research have you already done?

Comment: @Seanny123 I have integrated the question with some online entries which may be pertinent